# Parsing XML to java Object containing List attributtes

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I'm having a hard tie converting a xml file to java objects and would like to get some help. The problem is as follows:

I have one **Server** class which has 2 subclasses named **UserList** and **EventList**.

(**UserList** contains a List of Users) and **EventList** a List of Events.

I am supposed to read information from a file which contains instances from the class Event and all its information. My class Event is defined as follows:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Event {
@XmlElement
private String title;
@XmlElement
private List<Stand> stands;


public Event(String title, List<Stand> stands) {
    this.title = title;
    this.stands = stands;


}
```

and in my Main class I'm trying to unmarshall the xml with JAXBContext:

```
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Event.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();        
    File file = new File("exhibition1_v0.1.xml");
    Event event = (Event) unmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

    System.out.println("Event name :" +event.getTitle());
    for( Stand s: event.getStands()){
    System.out.println(s);
    }
```

The example XML file has an example stand:

```
<event>
<title>exhibition1</title>
<stands>
    <stand>
        <description>Stand 1</description>
        <area>37</area>
        <relativeDistanceSet>
            <distance>
                <description>Stand 2</description>
                <value>9</value>
            </distance>
            <distance>
                <description>Stand 3</description>
                <value>7</value>
            </distance>
            <distance>
                <description>Stand 4</description>
                <value>12</value>
            </distance>
        </relativeDistanceSet>
    </stand>
</stands>
.....
```

I am getting the following output:

```
Event name : exhibition1
Stand{descri=null, area=0.0, relativeDistanceSet=null}
```

And should be getting:

```
Event name : exhibition1
Stand{descri=Stand1, area=37.0, relativeDistanceSet={(description=Stand2, value=9),(description=Stand3, value=7),(description=Stand4, value=12)}}
```

Where is my error?

Comment: are your `Event`, `Stand` and other java classes really in `default` package (have no `package` declaration)? as well as your XML has no namespace(s) defined?

Comment: my Event Stand classes are in model package, and my code to parse xML in Main class, ui package.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to annotate the class Stand too.

Something like this (class members guessed based on your expected output):

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Stand {
@XmlElement
private String descri;
@XmlElement
private double area;
@XmlElement
private List<RelativeDistanceSet> relativeDistanceSet;
```